# In Windows 7, what's the way to bring up MS outlook if it's open?

Tags: outlook, keyboard, shortcut

I've searched the net and found I can define a keyboard shortcut in outlook : **`Ctrl+Alt+O`**, so that it will open an outlook window, but the problem is : if it's already open, it will open another one.

That's not what I was looking for, I want to bring up the window if it's already open, and I know there is a way to hold down a key and use tab to go through all apps and find outlook, since I'm using Java robot to auto execute some command, 
I need a shortcut so that if outlook is not open, open it, if it's already open, bring focus to it and not to open another one.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is, When Outlook is pinned to your Task Bar in Windows 7 you can open Outlook by pressing the **Windows Key** on your keyboard and the number representing its position within the bar.

Example on my computer I will press  <kbd>**Windows Key + 5**</kbd>

[image]

The same trick will work when Outlook is already running to bring focus quickly back. it is much quicker than  <kbd>**ALT+TAB**</kbd>  to cycle through all your opened applications.

> I think it only works for the first 10 applications or Quick Launch bar, where you use 0 to open the 10th app.

**Edit**

Another option is creating shortcut  and adding **`/recycle switch`** to prevent Outlook from opening an extra window each time you use your keyboard shortcut.

It should open if it's not open and also bring focus if its open

Example:

Locate **`OUTLOOK.EXE`**

1-*Right click outlook.exe **>** Send to **>** Desktop (create shortcut)*

2- *Right click on shortcut you created and edit Target (Type a space behind quotes and add* `/recycle`)

[image]

Comment: What if my Java app doesn't know it's position ? Even if it does know the position on my PC, if someone else use my app on his machine, it might not work, I have to re-program, it will be best if it can come in to focus by pressing something like WinKey-O or something similar to that effect ... absolute, not relative.

Comment: Yes, better, although not out of the box, I'll have to do something to user's PC, but better than original approach ! I'm still looking for a less invasive solution. So far this is the best one. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can use a batch file. This worked on my machine. I just couldn't figure out how to give outlook the focus if it is already running.

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq outlook.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "outlook.exe">NUL
IF not "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
    start /B "" "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\outlook.exe"
)
```